# Dllimport in c# from

Tags: c#, c++

First of all, I am new to C#. I am using vs2010.

I am trying to include a dll in my C# project. I was following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). I made the dll. I want to include this dll using dllimport in C# project but I get error that dll doesnt exist. I tried giving full path, or added .dll file to current project, still no luck.

Please help.

Code:

```
[DllImport("MathFuncDll.dll")]
public extern static double Add(double a, double b);
double tt = Add(15, 10);
```

Error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=3
  LinePosition=9
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
       at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at WpfApplication1.App.Main() in E:\projects\development\vs_test\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.DllNotFoundException
       Message=Unable to load DLL 'MathFuncDll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
       Source=WpfApplication1
       TypeName=""
       StackTrace:
            at WpfApplication1.MainWindow.Add(Double a, Double b)
            at WpfApplication1.MainWindow..ctor() in E:\projects\development\vs_test\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 31
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Example is a console app, you appear to be doing wpf gui app, and it appears to think it's a .net dll.

Comment: The dll is located in the same location as your compile program correct?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov look at the inner exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid stupid me.

It was a typing error. Though thanks a lot for dependency walker.

That is how you learn.

Answer (score 3):

The DLL may require some other DLL that is not on the path. Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check that.

You may also be hitting some kind of permissions on the folder where you have the DLL, like describe in this [case](http://web.archive.org/web/20110628012649/http://www.stillhq.com/aus-dotnet/archives2/msg00033.html).

If you are trying it in another machine other than your development machine, you may have to install the corresponding Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package.

Comment: Or the DLL itself might be in the wrong location (say, in the project directory, rather than the `bin\$(Configuration)` directory where the executable is)

Comment: I am on only one machine. I made .NET dll (simply copy pasted the example) and imported in another c++ code. Dependency walker gave no errors either. Thoughts please?

Answer (score 2):

Add the DLL to your project as a link and make sure the "copy to output directory" is set to "copy always" or "copy if newer".

If that doesn't work use Dependency Walker to figure out what dependencies you are missing and then do the same thing with those.

Comment: i check in dependency walker. There were no errors: Function Addis :
?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z Entry Point: 0x0001113B